UseMemo still re-rendering component
The following is a simplification of a component I've written. It has two tabs, and different content is displayed depending on which tab is selected (done by a button not included here).
There are two child components, a SimpleContent object that just displays static content, and a LoadedContent component that has to go away, make a call from a server to fetch data, and then render itself. What I would like to do is only make that server call once, so I don't want to re-render LoadedContent each time I select that tab. I want it to render the LoadedContent component once, even when I click to tab 1 and then back to tab 2.
I thought by using UseMemo to wrap the LoadedContent component that would work, but it doesn't - each time I click into tab 2, it reloads the content. How do I fix this please?
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import LoadedContent from './loadedContent';
import SimpleContent from './simpleContent';

const TabsPage = (props) => {

    const [tab, setTab] = useState("tab1");
    
    const tab2Display = useMemo(() => {
        return (
            <LoadedContent  />
        )
    }, [])

    return (
    
        <div>
            {tab === "tab1" ? 
                <SimpleContent />
            : 
                {tab2Display}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TabsPage;


In dev mode, or in production mode? Because in dev mode React explicitly always renders your component twice, to make sure you wrote code that knows how to deal with rerenders. That said: this code doesn't make a lot of sense: just put <LoadedContent  /> in your return directly, and make that component render itself properly regardless of how many times it gets rerendered.

If TabsPage is remounted it will obviously also redeclare and re-memoize the computed tab2Display value.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans so I have my UseMemo in the wrong place, it should be around the content that is loaded within the LoadedContent component?

And for clarity, Mike is specifically referring to the rendering of your app ui into a React.StrictMode component, which runs additional mountings and renderings to help surface logical issues and bugs in your code in non-production builds.

@Gerry there is no point in memoizing a component, React already only actually rerenders it if the props or state changed. That's the very foundation of React.

Understood, I see that now. I put the memoization there because I was struggling to stop the LoadedComponent from re-rendering, but I was obviously not doing that right. I'll take another look, thanks all for your comments.

To make sure that the LoadedContent component fetches data only once, you should move the loading logic into the parent component and store the loaded data in the state. Using useMemo alone won't prevent re-rendering because it recalculates on every render. Here's how you can implement this:
Create a state to hold the loaded content data.
Then use a useEffect call to fetch data when the component mounts, and pass the data into the LoadedContent component as a prop.
Here's an updated version of your TabsPage component:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import LoadedContent from './loadedContent';
import SimpleContent from './simpleContent';

const TabsPage = (props) => {
    const [tab, setTab] = useState("tab1");
    const [loadedData, setLoadedData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('YOUR_API_ENDPOINT'); // Replace with your API endpoint
                const data = await response.json();
                setLoadedData(data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            }
        };

        // Fetch data only once when the component mounts
        if (!loadedData) {
            fetchData();
        }
    }, [loadedData]);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setTab("tab1")}>Tab 1</button>
            <button onClick={() => setTab("tab2")}>Tab 2</button>

            {tab === "tab1" ? 
                <SimpleContent />
                : 
                loadedData ? <LoadedContent data={loadedData} /> : <p>Loading...</p>
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default TabsPage;

An even better solution, in my opinion, but something that would take more refactoring, is to use react-query. They have a useQuery hook that can fetch data from an endpoint, and then caches the result, so you can be very explicit with when you want to refetch the data. Here are the docs if you're interested.
In this case, it might look something like:
const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('YOUR_API_ENDPOINT'); // Replace with your API endpoint
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
};

const { data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['content'],
    queryFn: fetchData,
    refetchOnMount: false // just to demonstrate
})


Yes, this makes sense, my question came from a lack of understanding of react state and when it gets reset. Therefore I should be holding it in the parent object (your suggestion above), or else just hide the loaded component rather than releasing it when the tab changes. Thanks
